# introducing two equivalent adjectives

Tags: sentence-meaning, adjectives, punctuation, commas, mathematics

Let us consider the sentence

**We will study certain lattice, or discrete, particle systems.**

Let me explain what I am trying to say here. For my potential reader the expressions "lattice particle systems" and "discrete particle systems" are synonymous, and sometimes they have equivalent meanings. In this sentence I aim to establish a convention that those expressions mean *exactly* the same thing in the following text. (I would like to have two options because I am going to refer to such particle systems multiple times).

Have I chosen a legitimate way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence isn't very clear to me.
I suggest something like this:

> We will study certain lattice particle systems, *herein also referred to as discrete.*